# How can i show document type in my listview?

Tags: list, document-library, list-view, custom-list

I want to show my document types .xls , .png, .doc etc. I did not find it to show. only shows a picture of them. But i want to group them by this type. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

when you create or modify your view then go to Group section and use `Type(Icon Linked to Document)`

[image]

then you will get the results grouped by documenttypes

[image]

Comment: How can i use it ? Do you mean sharepoint designer or visual studio ? I trıed to do that in online list view modify . But i did not see this column.

Comment: I updeted my answer @f_gulay

Comment: I trıed this before but it is grouping them with an icon.

Comment: I added a picture of mine.

Answer (score 2):

Melad's screen capture is for SharePoint Online's "modern UI" while f_gulay's screen capture is from an on-prem version, or from SharePoint Online using the "Classic UI".

To get the file type as text in the Classic UI / On-prem UI will require a workflow. (The file type text is part of the library's data, but not selectable from a View.)

The workflow:

- Create a new column in your library (Example: "File Extension").
- Create a SP 2010 or SP 2013 style workflow.
- Add a "Set Field in Current Item" Action.
- Set the "field" to your new column.
- Set the "value" to "Current Item:File Type".
- Set the workflow to start on Created and on Changed.
- Create a view that groups on your new column.
- Upload documents. (this will run the workflow on each new document.)

The workflow:

[image]

The result:

[image]